# Regular expression for single number or groups with addition (+) and subtraction (-) mathematical operator

Tags: c#, regex, numeric, addition, subtraction

I need to create a regular expression that only accepts numbers and addition and subtraction characters.

I've defined the single number and groups pattern by this way 
`([1-9][0-9]*)`

I'm not able to add the definition for addition and subtraction characters.

I'd like to have all ok with something similar this example

Ex: `12 + 1 - 23 - 9 + 10`

Comment: `^\d+(?:\s*[+-]\s*\d+)*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve validation, I would recommend you tokenize it, but organize it by looking for an operator `[+-]` first then the number. Once tokenized you can verify in code if all operations are valid and **accumulate** a resultant total.

**Example**

```
var data = "12 + 1 - 23 - 9 + 10";

var pattern = @"(?<Operator>[+-]*)\s*(?<Number>\d+)";

var tokens =
   Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select (mt => new
             {
                 Operator = string.IsNullOrEmpty(mt.Groups["Operator"].Value)
                                  ? "+"   // Default to '+' if not found. (First Number)
                                  : mt.Groups["Operator"].Value,
                 Value    = mt.Groups["Number"].Value
             });
```

**Result To Accumulate**

[image]

Note it would also work if the numbers start out negative such as `-12 + 1 - 23 - 9 + 10` result:

[image]

---

Frankly one could be adding negative numbers. Here is a pattern to handle the *sign* of the number and process the sign and the operator together to determine and positive or negative accumulation:

```
var data = "-12 + 1 + -2 - -3";

var pattern = @"(?<Operator>[+-]*)\s*(?<Sign>[-]*)\s*(?<Number>\d+)";

var tokens =
   Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
        .OfType<Match>()
         .Select (mt => new
                  {
                    Operator = string.IsNullOrEmpty(mt.Groups["Operator"].Value)
                                     ? 1   // default to + if not found (First Number)
                                     : mt.Groups["Operator"].Value == "-" ? 0 : 1,
                    Sign     = string.IsNullOrEmpty(mt.Groups["Sign"].Value)
                                     ? 1   // default to positive
                                     : 0,
                    Value    = mt.Groups["Number"].Value
                  })
         .Select (token => new
              {
                  Postive = (((token.Operator & token.Sign) > 0) || 
                             ((token.Operator + token.Sign) == 0)) 
                             ? "+" : "-",
                  Value = token.Value
               })
```

**Result To Accumulate**

[image]

**Note** that minus a `-3` makes it a `+3` when **accumulated**. ;-)

---

For completeness, here is a snapshot of the first `Select` before the operator and sign determination of the following second `Select` is done:

[image]

Which shows that two zeros signify two minuses, which need to be converted to a plus.

Comment: Note that `[1-9][0-9]*` is not equivalent to `\d+`: the first enforces you to start with a non-zero...